# Can't make UIBarButtonItem's action work

Tags: cocoa-touch, rubymotion

I've got a controller and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to show an `UIAlertView`. What I can't get to work is the `UIBarButtonItem`'s *action* parameter.

In my controller

```
class TapController < UIViewController
  def alert
    alert = UIAlertView.new
    alert.message = "It's working"
    alert.show
  end

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
    right_button = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithTitle("Go Deeper",
                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered,
                                                       target:self,
                                                       action:'alert')
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = right_button
  end
end
```

My `app/app_delegate.rb`:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    #UIScreen is the display the app runs on
    @window = UIWindow.new.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    controller = TapController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
    @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(controller)

    true
  end
end
```

So it's very simple, but the UIBarButtonItem's target or action attributes doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem.  In your app delegate, you need to call `alloc` instead of `new` on `UIWindow`.

```
@window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
```

Comment: Oh! AFAIK the new method is an OBJ c shorthand that does `alloc` and `init`. Do you know why it fails when using `new`?

Comment: Thank you so much! Totally missed this.

Comment: I don't know why it fails with `new`, but I've only seen it written with `alloc.init` in this case.